# Scaling up svg width, height and viewbox

Tags: html, css, svg, vector

I'm trying to scale up this particular `.svg` icon file:

https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme/blob/master/Papirus/16x16/devices/input-keyboard.svg

So I tried changing this line:

```diff
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16">
```

to this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
```

But the contents of the vector does not seem to be scaled up. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Set the viewbox to the original size - 16 x 16. Set the height and width to the desired size - 22 x 22.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `transform: scale(4);`